# Failed to restore csproj file while i want to publish project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to make exe file of C# code and I used this settings to create it in one file. However, it Failed while it restoring csproj and it return this error message:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Email-gen, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>Email-gen -> C:\Users\Mohammed\source\repos\Email-gen\Email-gen\bin\Release\net6.0\Email-gen.dll
2>------ Publish started: Project: Email-gen, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>Determining projects to restore...
2>Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
2>Unable to find package Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
2>Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
2>Failed to restore C:\Users\Mohammed\source\repos\Email-gen\Email-gen\Email-gen.csproj (in 774 ms).
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

This csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Email_gen</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

This is settings of publisher
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure the Nuget base source is enabled, as according to your logs it's only searching packages offline.

Visual Studio Menu:
`Tools` => `Options` => `Package sources` => enable `nuget.org`

Also, to make your project independent from your VS settings this could be added to the `.csproj`:

```
   <RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    </RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
```

P.S. I see `Visual studio 2017` in tags, but you can only use 2022 one to build .NET 6 apps